# How do I compare 2 samples with different distributions?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

How do I compare 2 samples with different distributions?
The 1st sample (n=78) failed normality test, and the second sample (n=48, control) passed it.
I got to compare these two if they are statistically different.
mean1=1,81; stdev1=1,12; Q1, Q2, Q3=1,23; 1,58; 2,12;
mean2=1,93; stdev2=0,80; Q1, Q2, Q3=1,33; 1,82; 2,40.
Mann-Whitney rank sum test showed there is no statistically significant difference (U=1551,50; p=0,108). Can I use this result or shld I do some other tests considering Mann-Whitney is to compare samples with the same distribution?

Comment: The null hypothesis is that the distributions are the same. The alternative is a location shift. But the distribution is unspecified.

Comment: You first need to decide on what differences in the distributions are important.  Is it a difference in means, medians, variances?  Means *and* variances?  The whole distribution?  Those are subject matter and NOT statistical decisions.  Then one can choose a statistical test or estimator.  And you'll need to choose between a hypothesis test and an estimate.  (For me a hypothesis test without any idea the power of the test seems not very informative.)

Comment: My comment was referring to the Mann-Whitney test.

Answer (score 0):

Sample size of the population is different thing and depend on the intended usage, how ever to check the consistency or homogeneity of the sample we usually classify the sample as parametric or non-parametric and based on this classification the test statistics is selected. the common statistics in scientific work used is mostly ANOVA (Analysis of variance) which check for the assumption that the data is coming from the same distribution and thus have similar variance with certain p-value. The common tests apart from . Apart from Mann-Whitney there are many more statistics like  Pettitt's test, Standard normal homogeneity test, Buishand's test and Von Newmann's test. however selection and application is based on the methods and intended usage of the results. I hope that is of some help